# Binary matrix multiplication: finding the number of ones

Tags: matrices, binary-operations

Consider a binary matrix $\mathbf A_n$ corresponding to values $0$ to $2^n-1$ where each row represents a length $n$ binary representation of a real number. For example, for $n=3$ we have

$\mathbf A_3=\begin{bmatrix}
     0   &  0   &  0\\
     1    & 0  &   0\\
     0   &  1  &   0\\
     1   &  1   &  0\\
     0   &  0  &   1\\
     1  &   0   &  1\\
     0   &  1  &   1\\
     1  &   1    & 1
\end{bmatrix}.$

Consider two arbitrary non-zero binary vectors $\mathbf v_1, \mathbf v_2$ of length $n$ (column vector) such that $\mathbf v_1\neq\mathbf v_2$. Now, assume $\mathbf u_1=\mathbf A\mathbf v_1$ (mod $2$) and $\mathbf u_2=\mathbf A\mathbf v_2$ (mod $2$) . I can verify for an arbitrary $n$ that $\mathbf u_1.^*\mathbf u_2$ (element-wise multiplication) has always $2^{n-2}$ ones. For example, for $\mathbf A_5$ and
$$
\mathbf v_1=\begin{bmatrix}0,\ 0,\ 1,\ 1,\ 1\end{bmatrix}^T,
\mathbf v_2=\begin{bmatrix}0,\ 1,\ 0,\ 0,\ 0\end{bmatrix}^T
$$
We have 
$$
\mathbf u_1.^*\mathbf u_2=\begin{bmatrix} 0\     0\     0 \    0 \    0  \   0\     1 \    1\     0 \    0 \    1  \   1 \    0  \   0 \    0  \   0 \    0 \    0\     1\  1\     0 \    0  \   0\     0 \    0\     0 \    0 \    0 \    0 \    0\     1\     1\end{bmatrix}^T
$$
of length $2^5$ which has $2^{5-2}=8$ ones. I am looking for an analytical way to prove this.

Answer (score 0):

We can start by observing that $\mathbf u_i$ has $2^{n-1}$ 1s because if we take any set bit of $\mathbf v_i$ we can pair up the rows of $\mathbf A_n$ which differ in that bit and the corresponding rows of $\mathbf v_i$ will also differ.

So essentially what we want to do is show that the different $\mathbf u_i$ are independent.

We can use the same approach, doubled up. Let $x_1$ be the index of a bit which is set in $\mathbf v_1$ but not in $\mathbf v_2$, and $x_2$ vice versa. Group the rows of $\mathbf A_n$ into groups of four such that in each group they differ only in those two indices. Then two of the corresponding rows of each $\mathbf u_i$ will be 0 and two will be 1, but the index which determines the parity is different, so exactly one of the four has a double-1.

Answer (score 0):

Let us choose random row vector $x_i$ of $A_n$ uniformly at random. Then $x_i \cdot v_1$ is $0$ or $1$ with equal probability and similarly for $v_2$. Since both situations are independent, the probability that both are one is equal to $\frac{1}{4}$. And therefore the number of positions where both $u$s are one is equal to $\frac{1}{4} \cdot 2^n=2^{n-2}$.